# Jinja2 route specification

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Good evening. 
I'm developing a Politicians Wiki in Python-Flask API. 
As the name suggests the platform behaves like Wikipedia and there is a **flag** function to report incorrect content. 
To create that function I created an extra table named Flag and associated to all my webapp classes, as in: **Politicians**, **Proposals**, **Organizations**, **Roles**. Basically, everything that can be flagged for misleading info.

I linked those table in a One-to-Many relationship.
1 Politician have 0..* Flags
1 Proposal have 0..* Flags, etc..

The problem is when I try to print all the information in one page, I need something to separate the flags by classes in order to get different routes for each class individual page.

```
{% for flag in flags %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{flag.flagtitle}}</td>
                                <td>{{flag.flagreason}}</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><a href="/politician/{{ flag.politician }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
                                <td><form action ="/delete_flag/{{ flag.idflag }}" method="POST">
                    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete" class="fa fa-times"></span> delete</button>
                </form></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

In here, I only can see the politicians flagged topics and can only get the route for that Politician' flag info, right?

How do I parse the flags I get to get the right class route to follow? Should I refactor the routes and add the ClassID(PoliticianID e.g) to flag table and then go

> /api/flag/id

I'm really confused and I actually don't know what's the best approach..

Any good ideas?

**Admin controller**(where I see all the flagged content)

```
@users_blueprint.route("/admin", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def admin():
    form = SignupForm()
    flags = db.session.query(Flag).all()
    users = db.session.query(User).all()
    if (current_user.get_urole()) == "admin":
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.validate() == False:
                return render_template('admin.html', form=form)
            else:
                newuser = User(form.first_name.data, form.last_name.data, form.email.data, form.password.data,
                               "member")
                db.session.add(newuser)
                db.session.commit()
                flash(u'Welcome to POLEX', 'info')
                return redirect(url_for('home.home'))

        elif request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("admin.html", users=users, form=form, flags=flags)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home.home'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to group the flags by type.  The easiest way is probably to separate the flags by type in your controller and then pass that information into the template.

```
flags_by_type = {flag_type: [] for flag_type in flag_types}
for flag in flags:
    flags_by_type[flag.type].append(flag)
render(..., flags=flags_by_type)
```

Then, in your template you could loop over the flag types and then loop over the flags for each type in a nested fashion.